# Как привести фото к нужному размеру?

Tags: php

Добра всем.
Ребята подскажите как сделать фотку нужного размера 1074х765. 
Использую graphickmagick
Вот функция которую набросал, но она масштабирует не совсем так как нужно. Что делать как быть, нужна помощь.

```
function saveBig($savefile){
$image=new Gmagick($savefile);

$width=$image->getimagewidth();
$height=$image->getimageheight();

$standartWidth=1024;
$standartHeight=756;

$masWidth=1300;
$masHeight=900;

$kw=$width/$masWidth;
$kh=$height/$masHeight;

$wx=$width/$kw;
$hy=$height/$kh;

$image->setCompressionQuality(75);
$image->resizeimage($wx,$hy,null, 1, true);

$x=(($masWidth-$standartWidth)/2);
$y=(($masHeight-$standartHeight)/2);


$image->cropimage($standartWidth, $standartHeight, $x,$y);
$image->writeimage($savefile);
}
```

Comment: Вам как нужно привести, целиком вписать, или с обрезкой невписавшегося?

Comment: Ну я в начале хотел целиком, потом подумал что так не возможно, и решил обрезать то что не вписывается.